# Turn off the Quen sign

Tags: the-witcher-2

The Quen sign is extremely useful to protect yourself against enemy attacks. The base version also doesn't last long, but if you upgrade Quen itself or increase your sign intensity Quen can last for a pretty long while. The disadvantage being that you don't regenerate vigor while Quen is active.

After battle, you don't want to enter the next one with an almost depleted Quen and an empty vigor bar, caused by the still active Quen which prevented vigor regeneration. It would be quite convenient to just disable Quen after battle. Is there any quick way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can always meditate to pass time.

Alternatively, when you're down to only one enemy left, you can simply let him beat on you for as long as it takes Quen to finish its duration. Of course, this means you need to be able to defeat a single enemy without using Quen, which, depending on skill and game difficulty, might be easier said than done.

Comment: Although this sounds absolutely plausible and I would expect it to work, meditating does not cause Quen to end, the countdown continues where it left before you started the meditation. This is likely a bug, but it unfortunately makes this method useless.

Comment: Eh? I could have sworn I used this at least once before...

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the Quen sign by sheathing Geralt's sword and double tapping the cast sign key. See [here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Quen_sign) (Witcher 2 notes).